# Set decimal places to display using Javascript for an auto-calculated number

Tags: javascript

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updatesum() {
    document.add_new_report.total.value = (document.add_new_report.cheque.value -0) + (document.add_new_report.cash.value -0);
    }
    </script>
```

Input Fields

```
<input type="text" name="cheque" id="cheque" onChange="updatesum()" />
<br>
<input type="text" name="cash" id="cash" onChange="updatesum()" />
```

Result Field

```
<input type="text" id="total" readonly="readonly" name="total"  />
```

If i enter **100.100** in cheque and **200** in cash it is displaying total as **300.1** but i want to display **300.100**  how is it possible ??

Comment: So your question is about number/string formatting rather than actually adding field values?  If that is the case, you may want to change your question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.add_new_report.total.value = ((document.add_new_report.cheque.value -0) + (document.add_new_report.cash.value -0)).toFixed(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to used the `.toFixed()` Method

[Reference](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic2.html)

> ```
> function updatesum() {
> document.add_new_report.total.value = 
>   (
>     (document.add_new_report.cheque.value -0) 
>     + (document.add_new_report.cash.value -0)
>     ).toFixed(3);
> }
> ```

[Fiddle Example](http://tinkerbin.com/PXOKVY6i)